# Can i build an android and ios app with jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, ios

Please, am a web developer. I just built a web app for a school to manage their results and fees.

Now, i intend to build an app on android and ios so its 'easier' for both staff and students to get notifications and interact better.

Is JQuery mobile the asnwer? 
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Just as a heads up, when you write questions try to be as specific as possible, also try to describe what you tried before coming here to ask.

Comment: @LuigiPower.. I am new here... I'd do better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile doesn't create an application for Android nor for iOS, it only makes websites look better on said platforms.

To create a real, native, application for Android you should use Android Studio. To do the same for iOS you need XCode and MAC OS X.

But, if you prefer to write websites, Apache Cordova does what you need. Allows you to create apps for any platform using your usual HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I'll drop the link here so you can check it out.

https://cordova.apache.org/

Another approach is creating a basic Android and iOS app that simply opens a web page (your website), but it is most of the time lacking in performance. If this last approach interests you, just look up "WebView" for Android, "UIWebView" for iOS (Obviously you'll need Android Studio and XCode)

## EDIT

This is an old answer, now a ton of different technologies exist to build multiplatform applications, without even losing out on performance (for example, see react-native)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already built the app using JQuery mobile and want to make it into an app I recommend looking at Cordova (PhoneGap) https://cordova.apache.org/

For notifications etc I found https://www.pushwoosh.com/ to have the best integration

Comment: Thanks. i'd look into that